# Scrollbar did not work in WordPress

Tags: css

When I go to bottom of my website, I can't go back to top with the scrollbar. What might be the problem?

and I also have some errors on the browser console.

```html
#wise-ticker .owl-controls,
#wise-ticker .owl-item {
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.wise-ticker-title {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 padding-left: 20px;
}
```

http://londonpostjournal.com/

Comment: The scrollbar is working fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: http://londonpostjournal.com/category/life-style/

Comment: If you have some errors on the browser console, do you think it would be worth mentioning what those errors are in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code in your general stylesheet

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Hope this will works for you.

Comment: Not advised. This will always have a scrollbar open in browsers in Windows even if the scrollbar is not required. One could rather use `overflow-y: auto;`